# SQL subquery rows as GROUP BY columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, aggregate-functions

I wanna have columns in the response for each `task_type` with counts grouped by `date_trunc('day')` and `user_id`. So once the whole query runs it would return `task_type_1` column and the field value would be the number of tasks with that type for a given user for that given day.

So far I have this which runs but not sure how to add the task_type grouping to this query:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id,
  date_trunc('day', workforce_assigned_tasks.created_at) AS day,
  SUM(workforce_assigned_tasks.duration) AS duration,
  SUM(workforce_assigned_tasks.earnings_cents) AS earnings_cents,
  SUM(workforce_assigned_tasks.subtask_count) AS subtask_count,
  WHAT GOES HERE?
FROM users
JOIN workforce_assigned_tasks ON workforce_assigned_tasks.user_id = users.id
JOIN workforce_tasks ON workforce_assigned_tasks.workforce_task_id = workforce_tasks.id
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', workforce_assigned_tasks.created_at), users.id;
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, date_trunc('day', wat.created_at) AS day,
       SUM(wat.duration) AS duration,
       SUM(wat.earnings_cents) AS earnings_cents,
       SUM(wat.subtask_count) AS subtask_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE wt.task_type_1 = 1)
FROM users u JOIN
     workforce_assigned_tasks wat
     ON wat.user_id = u.id JOIN
     workforce_tasks wt
     ON wat.workforce_task_id = wt.id
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', wat.created_at), u.id;
```

I am guessing that `task_type` is in `workforce_tasks`.

Note that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: In this case I would have to repeat this line as many times as many types there are in the DB: `WHERE wt.task_type_1 = 1`? Isn't there a way to have a loop somehow?

Comment: No, but you can copy and past the line, changing the parameter on each line.

Comment: One more question. Can it be returned as json field like col name `tasks_counts` and json value `{ "type_1": 10, "type_2": 20 }` somehow? I spent some time on it but couldn't figure.

Comment: @SeanMagyar . . . You can construct a JSON field using the JSON constructors and functions in Postgres.